# How to link to the WordPress WP rest api from a custom HTML email?

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, email

I have a plugin that uses WordPress wp rest api to to register a custom end point with register_rest_route() that invoke a callback that sends an HTML email to the logged in user, this HTML email has a link inside it that should hit back the rest api and should route to another custom route created with register_rest_route( ) function that should send the user age in the route params and again as a result a callback will be invoked and it should use the user age info and do something with it.  I am able to send an email and view it in the inbox however when I press the link in the email(The link is something like this: http://127.0.0.1/myplugin/wp-json/mynamespace/v1/user/25) I don't hit the end point and get:  {"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method","data":{"status":404}} , on chrome debug console the error message is "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://127.0.0.1/myplugin/wp-json/mynamespace/v1/user/25 "

```
//code for custom end points inside my plugin..

function my_register_endpoints(){


   register_rest_route( 
      // routes that sends an email is working
       .
       .
       .
   );

   register_rest_route(

      'mynamespace/v1',
      'user/(?P<age>[\d]+)',
      array(
          'methods' => 'POST',
          'callback' => 'my_callback',
          'args' => array(
                  'age' => array(
                      'required' => true,
                      'validate_callback' => function($param, $request, $key) {
                        return is_numeric( $param );
                       }
                  )
          ),
          'permission_callback' => function (WP_REST_Request $request) {

              if(!is_user_logged_in()){
                  return new WP_Error('login error',__('You are not logged in','My-Error'));
              }
              return true;

          }
      )

   );

 }

}

add_action('rest_api_init','my_register_endpoints');

function my_callback(WP_REST_Request $request){
  //should do something with $request['age']
  $age=$request['age'];
}
```

Will be glad if someone would be able to explain and give some examples about the process of hitting the wp rest api from a custom html email? How to do it? Can it be a regular link or should I use Ajax requests with plain JS / JQuery / Angular $http in my custom html email and invoke the call when hitting the link inside the email ?

( I am using mailcatcher to view the the emails, I am testing my wordpress site on XAMPP on localhost )

Answer (score 0):

Try using a custom page template rather than trying to call an endpoint from a link.  That template can then call your endpoint if needed, either via AJAX or from the page template php directly.

Comment: Thank you Brian, It makes sense, I understand that the link in my email should link to this custom page template and maybe send the data to that page as query string and then the page will have a link or button that invoke the end point function of my custom route. I will try to take this approach for now. I am new to WordPress but from what I understand I will need to create files in my child theme and I wanted to have all the logic and pages related to the plugin to be in only in my plugin folder. do you know if it is possible to create custom page templates inside the plugin?